# DB4O: Need to use GenericList<T> outside of using block of connection

Tags: c#, db4o

I am using `DB4O` to store my objects. Please find below code `to retrieve objects` from DBO4 DB.

```
public IList<T> GetList<T>()
        {
            IList<T> list = null;
            using (IObjectContainer db = Db4oEmbedded.OpenFile(Db4oEmbedded.NewConfiguration(), fullFilePath))
            {
                list = db.Query<T>(typeof(T));
            }
            return list;
        }
```

**The question is**, I **CAN NOT apply C# 'foreach' loop outside of using block**. It gives me an error "Exception of type 'Db4objects.Db4o.Ext.DatabaseClosedException' was thrown." once I start traversing my List `outside of Using block`

I **am able to apply C# 'foreach' loop inside using block**, **but I wants to use my generic list to another code layer.** So, I must need my generic list object outside of using block.

Please give me solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

1. handle the disposal of the db object yourself
2. grab all data you need from the database (via `ToList` for example), which iterates the `IEnumerable<T>` and return that.

Comment: Femaref, Thanks very much. Your 2nd option really works... Another point I wants to know that, 1) for each and every connection, Should I need to use 'Db4oEmbedded.NewConfiguration()' in connection object every time whenever I wants to connect it? Is it a right way? 2) I noticed that, whenever I perform any operation in DB4O, it looks like it is taking approx 1 sec to returns the response from DB file (I stored simple 5 records of POCO objects).. Is this okay?

Comment: I have no experience with db4o, sorry. Maybe make that another question?

Answer (score 3):

Just adding to 'Femaref' answer & comments:

1) Yes, you need a new configuration for each connection.
2) Opening the database takes a while. db4o needs to read up meta data, check that the transactions have finished etc.

In general, you shouldn't open and close the container for each operation completely. That takes a lot of time just to open and close the database. I guess you want to use a new object container for each operation to have a transaction for each operation.

I recommend you to change the implementation a little. Open the object container when you application starts. And close it when you shut down the application. And then use [session containers](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/net35/reference/Content/advanced_topics/session_containers.htm) for each operation. That should be a lot faster, since db4o doesn't need to to all the initialization work.

Like this:

```
// Open the container once for the life-time of your application
IObjectConainer rootContainer = Db4oEmbedded.OpenFile(......)

public IList<T> GetList<T>()
{
    using (IObjectContainer db = rootContainer.Ext().OpenSession())
    {
                    // As Femaref said, use to list to 'eagerly' load all data
        return db.Query<T>(typeof(T)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Gamlor. The information you provided really worth!!

Comment: Gamlor, In my case I am storing data in 2 different database file based on my business rules. Could you please let me know that How would I open the container for the life-time of application for 2 different DB files?

Comment: Well you can open multiple root containers. Just use 'Db4oEmbedded.OpenFile' and assign that container to different fields. I don't know your app and what is the best way for you. You could keep the root container in a dictionary and then choose the right container according to the key. Or use another way to select the right container. And then use the .Ext().OpenSession() on the selected container.